How to send a pdf with messsage through whatsapp Intent Android Studio
Not able to send pdf files through whatsapp intent in Android Studio.
Intent whatsappIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND,Uri.parse(
    "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+919999999999&text=This is a Demo Message"));

whatsappIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

whatsappIntent.setType("application/pdf");

whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(whatsappIntent);

This is the Android code, but its not working.
I am only able to send messages but not pdf file.

What is the value of uri? Where does it come from? Are you sure that you have access to it?

@CommonsWare URI is pointing to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.practive/files/demo.pdf       File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"demo.pdf");Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); -- that has not been useful in several years. Other apps do not have access to your content. Use FileProvider to make your content available to other apps. FWIW, I cover FileProvider in this chapter of this free book.

Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("application/pdf");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath)); // Replace filePath with the path to your PDF file
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); // Set WhatsApp package name to ensure it opens in WhatsApp
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsappIntent, "Send PDF via..."));
Make sure to replace "file://" + filePath with the actual file path of your PDF file. And by setting the package to "com.whatsapp", you ensure that the intent is explicitly directed to WhatsApp.

Hi, Thanks for the reply. Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.billbook/files/demo.pdf"), whatsapp is opening but it is not sending the pdf file. And how to open a whatsapp with unknown number.
